# Performance Difference bet RAFT Orderer and Orderer with Kafka(Latency, Throughput, TPS)

Tags: performance, apache-kafka, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, raft

Did anyone compare performance(Latency, Throughput, TPS) between orderer with Kafka and RAFT Orderer?

I could see here a considerable difference in terms of latency, throughput, and TPS.

I tried with the same setup with the same resource configuration on two different VM(the Only difference is the orderer system).

Note: Used Single orderer in both networks.Fabric Version: 1.4.4

Orderer with Kafka is more efficient than RAFT. I am using the default configuration for RAFT and Kafka.

I tried with a load generator at a rate of 100 TPS. WIth Kafka all parameters are fine(latency- 0.3 to 2 sec) whereas using RAFT, latency is gradually increasing 2 to 15+ seconds, the tx failure rate is also high.

What could be the reason for this considerable difference in terms of TPS, throughput, and latency?

Please correct If I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For starters I would not run performance tests using a single orderer. These fault tolerance systems are there to handle distribution and consensus of a distributed system, so by running a single orderer you are fundamentally removing the reason they exist. It's as if you are comparing two sports cars on a dirt road and wonder which is the fastest.

Then there are other things that come into play, such as if you connect the services over TLS, the general network latency as well as how many brokers/nodes you are running.

Chris Ferris performed an initial performance analysis of the two systems prior to the release of Raft, and it seemed it was both faster and could handle almost twice as many transactions per second. You can read his blog post here: [Does Hyperledger Fabric perform at scale?](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/blockchain/2019/04/does-hyperledger-fabric-perform-at-scale/)

You should also be aware of the double-spending problem and key collisions that can occur if you run a distributed system under high load. You should take necessary steps to avoid this, which can cause a bottle-neck. See [this](https://medium.com/@gatakka/how-to-prevent-key-collisions-in-hyperledger-fabric-chaincode-303700716733) Medium post about collisions, and Hyperledger Fabric's own documentation on setting up a [high throughput network](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/master/high-throughput).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I already tried with multiple orderers for both consensus(RAFT, Kafka). Now my observation is Raft gives better TPS for the same configuration. I have gone through the articles you shared above, it really helped me.